# How to Convert .CER certificate to .CRT

Tags: system-installation, openssl, certificates

I tried to to Convert `Fiddler.CER` certificate to `.CRT` format:

```bsh
$ openssl x509 -in FiddlerRoot.cer -out FiddlerRoot.crt
unable to load certificate
139962232211264:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

$ strings FiddlerRoot.cer
0g1+0)
"Created by http://www.fiddler2.com1
DO_NOT_TRUST1!0
DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot0
201116174559Z
240215174559Z0g1+0)
"Created by http://www.fiddler2.com1
DO_NOT_TRUST1!0
DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot0
Z0X0
hG1)0v1
]0qf
_H.^K
r?XxY
```

Maybe it is a problem specifically to `FiddlerRoot.cer`, but here is the strange part, quoting from [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/system-wide-fiddler-certificate-on-ubuntu):

> I noticed that the FiddlerRoot certificate that I was trying to add to the system didn't look like what I imported into Firefox (The Firefox one contain the key info).  I exported the certificate I had in FireFox and updated the system certs with that file

I found that it is exactly the case for me as well. Here is why it is strange.

- The `FiddlerRoot.cer` file was downloaded from http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/FiddlerRoot.cer
- Trying to convert with `openssl` like above failed.
- However if I imported the *very* file to Firefox, then export it as `.crt` manually, my Unbuntu system will recognize that `.crt` file (but not the `.cer` file)

So the `FiddlerRoot.cer` is good, just I haven't found a good way to convert it to `.crt` using command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.cer` and `.crt` are just file extensions, or three letters. The important part is what is within those files.

It looks like the file `FiddlerRoot.cer` is a DER encoded certificate, which OpenSSL doesn't understand by default as it expects a PEM encoded file.  To help it, add `-inform DER` to the command.  It also outputs in PEM, so if that's what you're after, then you'll be OK with just that.

```
$ openssl x509 -inform DER -in FiddlerRoot.cer -out FiddlerRoot.crt
```

Comment: Super! Thanks for the clear explanation. Yes, FiddlerRoot.cer ***is*** a DER encoded certificate, and the above command works perfectly! And yes, output in PEM is what I'm after (my Unbuntu system can recognize that .crt file). Thx again!